# How to prepopulate drop down box with default custom value Html.DropDownListFor(...)

Tags: c#, asp.net, html.beginform

So I have a prefilled drop down list

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Item2.CategoryName, new SelectList(Model.Item1.Categories))
```

I want to add a default selection "All Categories" in the drop down list, how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Item2.CategoryName, new SelectList(Model.Item1.Categories),"All Categories")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually add your default item in your model list `Categories` before passing it to your view like this:

```cs
List<string> Categories = new List<string>();  
Categories.Add("All Categories");
```

then add the other items.

```cs
Categories.Add("Item1");
Categories.Add("Item2");
Categories.Add("Item3");
```